# Returning more than one result with pipe characer in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, pipe

when using the pipe character `|`, how do I get all the results defined in my regex to return?

Or does the `.search()` method only return the first result found?

Here is my code:

```
import re

bat.Regex = re.compile(r'Bat(man|mobile|copter|bat)')

matchObject = batRegex.search('Batmobile lost a wheel, Batcopter is not a chopper, his name is Batman, not Batbat')

print(matchObject.group())
```

Only the first result `'batmobile'` is returned, is it possible to return all results?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `findall`

Comment: I have treid matchObject = batregex.findall('...')
it just give me an error:
Attribute error: 'list' has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [official documentation for "re" module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

Excerpts from the docs linked:

- findall() matches all occurrences of a pattern, not just the first one as search() does.
- `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`
  Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression and return a corresponding match object.
- `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)` Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings (Note here: Not a match object which is only one match)

```py
import re
batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(man|mobile|copter|bat)')

results = batRegex.findall('Batmobile lost a wheel, Batcopter is not a chopper, his name is Batman, not Batbat')
results
```

output:

```
['mobile', 'copter', 'man', 'bat']
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. My syntax was weird ^~^